# How do I pull the live weather radar from the new (2020) NWS Weather Radar API?

Tags: dataset, weather, weather-api

[NWS has depricated](https://www.weather.gov/idp/ridge2landing) their old (pre 2020) weather radar site [here](https://www.weather.gov/jetstream/ridge_download).

I am trying to find their new API endpoint for pulling the live weather radar image for a lat/long point.  All I've been able to find about it is just [JSON feeds](https://www.weather.gov/documentation/services-web-api) for forecast.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way (that I know of) to do this anymore. If there is, it is well hidden. The best I can do is use their endpoint with lat/lon and it will show the closest weather forecast office - which will get you close... but not the actual radar needed.

For my answer I would suggest using MRMS or a national level-2 mosaic. I am not sure how your maps are setup so this may not be ideal. However, you can find them here :

Level-2 Mosaic Files :

https://mrms.ncep.noaa.gov/data/RIDGEII/L2/CONUS/

MRMS (Multi-Radar-Multi-Sensor) :

https://mrms.ncep.noaa.gov/data/2D/